# Failing to run external Bash program — /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run a CLI tool in Linux (Mint) which allows me to edit subtitles. It is named `subedit`: [github link](https://github.com/helixarch/subedit/blob/master/README.md). In order to run it, I've added executable permission with `chmod +x` and added it to the path in bash. However, when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
bash: /home/main/Documents/shellTools/subedit/subedit: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'm not very experienced with external bash programs and forgot to do something that would be obvious in hindsight.

When I do `echo $PATH` this is the output:

```
/home/main/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/main/Documents/shellTools/subedit/
```

Could somebody please help?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: It appears something was installed improperly; `subedit` appears to be trying to run a script with a shebang of `!#/usr/bin/bash`, and you don't have `/usr/bin/bash` installed.

Comment: I tried to replicate one of the examples in the readme. I'm sure all files exists which I use as input and the path is correct

Comment: Some systems make either `/bin` a symlink to `/usr/bin` or vice versa.  Others don't.  The software has chosen to use `#!/usr/bin/bash` but your machine doesn't have that — it has `/bin/bash`.  You'll have to edit the file `/home/main/Documents/shellTools/subedit/subedit` to use `/bin/bash` instead of `/usr/bin/bash`.  You might consider reporting the issue to the developers.  You could also use (and/or suggest they use) `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which would find Bash anywhere on your PATH.  Or the compilation/configuration process should determine where Bash is on the target system and use that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't have bash installed, you can verify that by running

```
which bash
```

if the above command returns "bash not found", then you need to install it.
In case the above command returns a path, you can use the below command to add a symlink to the expected path

```
ln -s $(path from the above command) /usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. When I do `which bash`, the output is `/bin/bash`. When I do `ls -s $(/bin/bash) /usr/bin/bash`, the situation is not changed. When I try to do a command similar to that in the examples it still gives me the message: `bash: /home/main/Documents/shellTools/subedit/subedit: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: You can try `which cd`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `bash` is installed, (it usually is), change the first line of `subedit` from:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

---

**Or** if one would prefer not to edit `subedit`, try this one-liner covering what [*Al-waleed Shihadeh* suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244076/6136214):

```
ln -s "$(which bash)" /usr/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `termux-chroot` **ONCE!**

If you want to always run at the start of a session, be sure to check if it was never run before.

```
if [ -z $CHROOT ]; then
 CHROOT=1
 termux-chroot
fi
```